# What does the object mean in context of creating a CountVectorizer object?

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

I was trying to understand some code for natural language processing using python. Here `X` is dataframe containing all my emails (text data). I have written some comments with the code but still I do not understand what the comments mean.

Example: What does it mean by creating a `CountVectorizer` object? And what does the third line do and finally in the fourth line, why can't I use `print((X.get_feature_names()))` to see the feature names?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
#import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words=my_list) #create a countvectorizer object
X = cv.fit_transform(X) #Here the document term matrix is created
print((cv.get_feature_names()))
```

Comment: See Wikipedia article on [Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CountVectorizer is to count frequency of each word in each sentence.
In the third line, CountVectorizer object is created and it has not any function (it is empty).
The object trains what words are in the sentences except for stop_words (my_list) by fit method, and it transforms sentence into word-document matrix by transform method.
Fit_transform method is the combination of fit and transform method.

Here is the example.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
my_list = ['to', 'is']
X = ['NLP is hard to understand', 'I study NLP']

cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words = my_list)
X = cv.fit_transform(X)

pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns = cv.get_feature_names())
```

Because most sentence includes few words, it is not efficient to save the transformed sentence as array type. So using `X.toarray()`, X can be transformed as array.

cv has the information of words (by fit method), but X is just result and thus get_feature_names() is not defined for X.